# Why stacked bar chart bars is unable to filter the pie chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

here i am trying to build 2 graphs

Stacked barchart : years spent on language (up to 3years one stack ,5 and above another stack)

Pie chart :years of Experience.
getting the charts fine .but when i click on the any bars in stacked bar chart pie chart is not filtering.but pie able to filter stacked bar chart

sample data:

```
{
 years of exp : 1,
    Courses_taken: [ 
      {
             Language : " SAP BI 7.0",
             spent : 5.0,           
      }, 
      {
             spent : 5.5,
             Language : " SAP ECC 6.0"
      }
  ]}
```

any suggestions. why bar chart  is unable to filter pie? 
 [code here](https://jsfiddle.net/aej4hdy4/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to be complete.

Comment: @potatopeelings fiddle updated

Comment: The basic problem here is that your data isn't flat, and you're jumping through an awful lot of hoops to force it to work. If you can flatten your data into just `[{yearsOfExp, Language, spent}...]`, then this filtering would be pretty simple, and you wouldn't need to copy and paste so very much code. But filtering only works on rows, and you're trying to filter on a value that's buried within the row. For example, if you click on "ECC6.0", should that include the student with 2.5 years of experience or not?

Comment: hi @Gordon thank you for reply.yes,if we click on " ECC6.0" it should include 2.5 yrs.